# tensorflow neural network attempt

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to Tensorflow and was doing a beginner's tutorial on creating neural networks. At first the program was not working at all because of an error that read

```
Cannot feed value of shape (165,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_107:0', which has shape '(?, 1)
```

I figured that had to do with the shape of my tensor so I reshaped the variable `Y` by `reshape(-1,1)`. After that the program started working but when the model is trained, the cost and accuracy do not seem to change. It just stays on zero. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('sonar.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:60].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 60]


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labely = LabelEncoder()
Y = labely.fit_transform(Y)

Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2)

# hyperparmeter
learnRate = 0.3
eps = 10
costHistory = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype=float)
input1 = X.shape[1]
output = 1

hiddenLayer1 = 16
hiddenLayer2 = 16
hiddenLayer3 = 16
hiddenLayer4 = 16

x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,input1])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input1,output]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output]))
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,output])


#------------------------------------------------


def multi_perceptron(x1, weight, bias):
    layer1 = tf.matmul(x1, weight['h1']) + bias['b1']
    layer1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer1)

    layer2 = tf.matmul(layer1, weight['h2']) + bias['b2']
    layer2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer2)

    layer3 = tf.matmul(layer2, weight['h3']) + bias['b3']
    layer3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer3)

    layer4 = tf.matmul(layer3, weight['h4']) + bias['b4']
    layer4 = tf.nn.relu(layer4)

    outputLayer = tf.matmul(layer4, weight['out']) + bias['out']
    return outputLayer

weight = {
            'h1' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input1, hiddenLayer1])),
            'h2' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer1, hiddenLayer2])),
            'h3' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer2, hiddenLayer3])),
            'h4' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer3, hiddenLayer4])),
            'out' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer4, output]))
        }

bias = {
         'b1' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer1])),
         'b2' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer2])),
         'b3' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer3])),
         'b4' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hiddenLayer4])),
         'out' : tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output]))   
        }

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
y = multi_perceptron(x1,weight,bias)


costFuction = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = y,labels = y_))
trainStep = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learnRate).minimize(costFuction)

with tf.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.run(init)

    errHistory = []
    accHistory = []

    for e in range(eps):
        sesh.run(trainStep, feed_dict = {x1:xtrain, y_:ytrain})
        cost = sesh.run(costFuction, feed_dict = {x1:xtrain, y_:ytrain})
        costHistory = np.append(costHistory, cost)
        correctPred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accu = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPred, tf.float32))
        print('epoch: ', eps, ' - ', 'cost: ', cost, '-Training Accuracy: ', accu)
```

Here is what it outputs.

```
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_364:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_365:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_366:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_367:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_368:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_369:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_370:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_371:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_372:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_373:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are doing binary classification, you need to change your cost function from `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Also to calculate accuracy in this case, instead of using `argmax` you need to keep a threshold.

```
correctPred = tf.equal(y_, tf.cast((y>0.5), tf.float32))
accu = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPred, tf.float32))
print('epoch: ', e+1, ' - ', 'cost: ', cost, '- Training Accuracy: ', accu.eval(feed_dict = {x1:xtrain, y_:ytrain}))
```

Comment: sorry for my late reply but the program still is not working it is outputs pretty much the same thing as before epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_421:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
epoch:  10  -  cost:  0.0 -Training Accuracy:  Tensor("Mean_422:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

Comment: Hey! I ran your code and found that the problem was actually not in the optimiser, but in the cost function. I have made changes to the answer. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The cost function is not converging with present learning rate you have set I.e. 0.3. Please rerun with lower learning rate say 0.05.

Regards
Chandra